# Cannot execute Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64 binary inside docker container

Tags: docker, unity-game-engine, x86-64, arm64, il2cpp

I have an **IL2CPP** scripting backend Unity Android export taken from Unity editor version **2020.3.48f1** (Mac intel variant on Mac m1 machine) for target architecture **ARM64**.

When I try executing *il2cpp* binary file (located at *unityLibrary/src/main/Il2CppOutputProject/IL2CPP/build/deploy/netcoreapp3.1*) locally, it runs just file -

```
MacBook-Pro netcoreapp3.1 % ./il2cpp 

Options:
  --emit-null-checks                              Enables generation of null checks
...
```

*file* command output (ran locally) is -

```
MacBook-Pro netcoreapp3.1 % file il2cpp
il2cpp: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
```

Now I am trying to build the Android export project inside docker using base image **amazoncorretto:17** (ran with `--platform linux/amd64` option ie. docker container architecture is **x86_64** same as il2cpp binary file) but I keep getting error -

```
bash-4.2# ./il2cpp
bash: ./il2cpp: cannot execute binary file
```

*file* command output (ran inside docker container) is -

```
sh-4.2# file il2cpp
il2cpp: Mach-O 64-bit executable
```

*x86_64* is missing in above output (as opposed to when I run it on my host machine) but I don't know if its relevant.

Architecture of both docker container and file is same (both are `x86_64`).

Question: How can I run il2cpp (and complete Unity export Android build) in a docker image (preferably any version of *amazoncorretto*)?

I cannot figure out why the executable runs locally but not inside docker container.

Note: I ran my Mac generated **il2cpp** inside same base docker image on a *linux* host but it gives same error.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You're trying to run a Mach-O on Linux...

Comment: MacOS and Linux are different operating systems.  There are no MacOS-native containers; Docker Desktop works by running a hidden Linux VM.  You probably need to compile this tool on Linux, maybe via a multi-stage Dockerfile.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in comments, the reason why binary was not executing inside a linux container because it was built on mac.

By exporting Unity project on ubuntu machine and using it inside **amazoncorretto:17** docker container (on ubuntu machine as well), the script started executing.